# Instead of update, nested form creates a new one Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, updates, nested-forms

I have a form with 2 nested forms for a Professional (certificates and trainings). Each one has the association accepts_nested_attributes_for in the Professional model. I can create a new professional with his certificates and training. When I save, however, instead of updating the certificates and trainings a new one is created.

My Professional controller:

```
def edit
  @professional = Professional.find(params[:id])
  @component = Component.all
  cert = Certificate.where('professional_id = ?', params[:id])
  cert.each do |certificate|
    @certificate = certificate
  end
  tra = Training.where('professional_id = ?', params[:id])
  tra.each do |training|
    @training = training
  end
  @work = Work.all
  @charge = Charge.all
  @entities =Array.new
  TypeEntity.where("id IN (1,5)").each do |tent|
    @entities << tent.entities
  end
  @reg = Time.now.to_i.to_s
  @major = Major.all
  @action = 'edit'
  render layout: false
end

def update
  profesional = Professional.find(params[:id])
  if profesional.update_attributes(professional_parameters)
    flash[:notice] = "Se ha actualizado correctamente los datos."
    redirect_to :action => :index
  else
    profesional.errors.messages.each do |attribute, error|
      flash[:error] =  flash[:error].to_s + error.to_s + "  "
    end
    # Load new()
    @profesional = profesional
    render :edit, layout: false
  end
end

private
def professional_parameters
  params.require(:professional).permit(
    :name,
    :dni, 
    :professional_title_date, 
    {:major_ids => []}, 
    :date_of_tuition, 
    :code_tuition, 
    :professional_title, 
    :tuition, 
    :cv, 
    certificates_attributes: [
      :id, 
      :professional_id, 
      :work_id, 
      :charge_id, 
      :entity_id, 
      :num_days, 
      :start_date, 
      :finish_date, 
      {:component_work_ids => []}, 
      :certificate, 
      :other, 
      :_destroy
    ], 
    trainings_attributes: [
      :id, 
      :professional_id, 
      :type_training, 
      :name_training,
      :num_hours, 
      :start_training, 
      :finish_training, 
      :training, 
      :_destroy
    ]
  )
end
```

This are the models:

```
class Certificate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :charge
  belongs_to :professional
end

class Professional < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :majors
  has_many :certificates
  has_many :trainings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :certificates, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :trainings, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Training < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :professional
end
```

The form begins with this:

```
=simple_form_for([:biddings, @professional], html: { multipart: true }) do |f|
```

after that I have the 3 forms in a bootstrap wizard.

Comment: Where is your `Professional` Model? Pls paste it

Comment: Please share the edit view code in the question.

Comment: Can you share the code for entire edit view along with the nested form details(if they are in separate partial). If you think that your question is getting lengthy then you may want to add the code in Github Gist.

Comment: Did you figure this out? Im having the exact same issue, and its driving me nuts. After the form submits, it returns validation error, and creates a duplicate set of child records each time i do it.

Comment: am having the same problem, any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have `ID` attribute in `Hash` in your `Edit` form.
As your Model has One-to-Many,

```
   For each hash that does not have an id key a new record will be instantiated, unless 
   the hash also contains a _destroy key that evaluates to true.
```

Comment: Where do you see `one-to-one association`? Its `one-to-many association` look at the model `Professional `.